# Issue in invoking JAX-RPC web service from a java web service client

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am creating a JAX-RPC web service client but when I am invoking the webservice it is giving me error:

> org.apache.naming.ServiceRef cannot be cast to javax.xml.rpc.Service

**Client code**

```
Context ctx= new InitialContext();
Service service = (Service)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/service/ROServiceImplService");
QName portQName= new QName("http://services.nic.in","ROServiceImpl");
ROServiceImpl svc = (ROServiceImpl) service.getPort(portQName,ROServiceImpl.class);
String roCode=svc.getROCode(scForm.getEmpCode(),"ashish","6295");
```

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>
        serviceclient</display-name>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
            org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>config</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>debug</param-name>
                <param-value>2</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>detail</param-name>
                <param-value>2</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>validate</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>

            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

        </welcome-file-list>
         <service-ref>
            <description>WSDL Service ROServiceImplService</description>
            <service-ref-name>service/ROServiceImplService</service-ref-name>
            <service-interface>javax.xml.rpc.Service</service-interface>
            <wsdl-file>WEB-INF/wsdl/ROServiceImpl.wsdl</wsdl-file>

        </service-ref>
        <jsp-config>
            <taglib>
                <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-uri>
                <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
            </taglib>
            <taglib>
                <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
                <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
            </taglib>
            <taglib>
                <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-uri>
                <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
            </taglib>
            <taglib>
                <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-uri>
                <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
            </taglib>
            <taglib>
                <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld</taglib-uri>
                <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-template.tld</taglib-location>
            </taglib>
            <taglib>
                <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-uri>
                <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
            </taglib>
        </jsp-config>
    </web-app>
```

**ROServiceImpl Code**

```
package in.nic.services;

public interface ROServiceImpl extends java.rmi.Remote {
    public java.lang.String getROCode(java.lang.String empCode, java.lang.String uname, java.lang.String pwd) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

**ROServiceImpl.wsdl**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://services.nic.in" xmlns:impl="http://services.nic.in" xmlns:intf="http://services.nic.in" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsi="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <wsdl:types>
      <schema targetNamespace="http://services.nic.in" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:impl="http://services.nic.in" xmlns:intf="http://services.nic.in" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <element name="getROCodeResponse">
        <complexType>
         <sequence>
          <element name="getROCodeReturn" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
         </sequence>
        </complexType>
       </element>
       <element name="getROCode">
        <complexType>
         <sequence>
          <element name="empCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <element name="uname" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <element name="pwd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
         </sequence>
        </complexType>
       </element>
      </schema>
     </wsdl:types>

       <wsdl:message name="getROCodeResponse">

          <wsdl:part element="impl:getROCodeResponse" name="parameters"/>

       </wsdl:message>

       <wsdl:message name="getROCodeRequest">

          <wsdl:part element="impl:getROCode" name="parameters"/>

       </wsdl:message>

       <wsdl:portType name="ROServiceImpl">

          <wsdl:operation name="getROCode">

             <wsdl:input message="impl:getROCodeRequest" name="getROCodeRequest"/>

             <wsdl:output message="impl:getROCodeResponse" name="getROCodeResponse"/>

          </wsdl:operation>

       </wsdl:portType>

       <wsdl:binding name="ROServiceImplSoapBinding" type="impl:ROServiceImpl">

          <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

          <wsdl:operation name="getROCode">

             <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

             <wsdl:input name="getROCodeRequest">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

             </wsdl:input>

             <wsdl:output name="getROCodeResponse">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

             </wsdl:output>

          </wsdl:operation>

       </wsdl:binding>

       <wsdl:service name="ROServiceImplService">

          <wsdl:port binding="impl:ROServiceImplSoapBinding" name="ROServiceImpl">

             <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:9080/ehradmwebservice/services/ROServiceImpl"/>

          </wsdl:port>

       </wsdl:service>

    </wsdl:definitions>
```